# Unity Javascript - Mecanim animator state

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm having a big problem here. I need to know which animator state I'm currently in, in order to make something happen. I've been searching a lot on this matter but because the mecanim animation is so new there isn't much info about it. At least not for unityscript.

Hope someone can help,

Thanks,
Róbert Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't know JS, but the following C# lines should be easy to be translated.
Animator.[GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo.html) returns an [AnimatorStateInfo](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/AnimatorStateInfo.html) struct that describes the current animator state.

```
int stateId = Animator.StringToHash("Base Layer.State Name"); 
Animator anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
AnimatorStateInfo currentBaseState = anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0);

if (currentBaseState.nameHash == stateId )
{
  //you are in stateId
}
```

Like you see in the example above the animator state's name are hashed (for performance reasons) so you have to hash the name of the state using [Animator.StringToHash](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Animator.StringToHash.html) in order to retrieve the integer id associated with that particular state.

Comment: thanks for you answer, that is true it should be easy to translate. Still I find it very difficult hehe. But I will try more. Hope it works out eventually!

Answer (score 0):

IT'S DO NOT WORK
Try this: 
print (currentBaseState.nameHash +"         "+ stateId);

And play the animation. They are different

Answer (score 0):

NOVA, I realize your answer was 2 years ago but it matches if you use the "full path" instead of .nameHash.

obl.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo (0).fullPathHash == Animator.StringToHash ("Base Layer.StateName")